# Why $1/z * 1/\bar{z} = 1/2\pi \ln r$?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, distribution-theory, laplacian

I am learning about fundamental solutions for $P(\partial) = -\Delta$ and the solution is $K_{-\Delta} = \frac{1}{2\pi} \ln r$. One remark from my professor is that
$$
K_{-\Delta} = K_\partial * K_{\bar \partial} = \frac{1}{z} * \frac 1 {\bar{z}}.
$$
Therefore, we must have
$$
\frac{1}{2\pi} \ln r = \frac{1}{z} * \frac 1 {\bar{z}},
$$
where $r = \|z\|$. I am wondering why this is true. Note that $*$ is convolution here.

Comment: How are you defining convolution on the complex plane?

Comment: I can't make the integral converge, neither in circular coordinates. @CameronWilliams $z=x+iy$ is a function $\Bbb{R^2\to C}$. This is a convolution on $\Bbb{R}^2$.

Comment: @CameronWilliams I have no idea about this...

Comment: @reuns My professor said with a proper renormalization, we can make sense of this.